# How do I downgrade from Enterprise to Pro/backup files?

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to downgrade my system from Enterprise to Pro. I have an activation key. So, I know that I need to do a clean install.
So, I do not have a USB big enough to hold every single one of my video games (probably 1TB of space), and I'd like not to lose all of that information. Can I back it up without a USB?

Second, how in the world do I install Pro?

Comment: Did you try changing your product key to your Windows 10 Pro one in *Activation settings*?  See this [How to Downgrade from Windows 10 Enterprise to Windows 10 Pro](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/51564-downgrade-windows-10-enterprise-windows-10-pro.html)

Comment: There's no need to backup anything when changing from Enterprise to Pro. It only removes a few addons and disables a few policies afaik. You don't lose any file or information.

Answer (score 0):

If you have (or can create) at least two partions - C: for OS and D: for data/games/etc , then just copy/move required files and folder to non-OS partition and do clean install of Windows. Don't forget about "user profile folder", where all documents/save games/images are stored by default.

Same games and apps may require reinstallation after clean Windows install.